# Add field to react-hook-form based on value of another field

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a JS objects like below (this is just one of many)

```
const formInput= {
  Service_Name: {
    required: true,
    type: "text",
    constraint: {
      min: 3,
      max: 15,
      format: "alpha-hyphen-numeric"
    }
  },
  Content_Type: {
    required: true,
    type: "select",
    options: ["Markdown", "HTML"]
  },
  Remarks: {
    required: false,
    type: "text",
    constraint: {
      max: 30
    }
  }
};
```

I have to create form to capture the inputs of these fields. Since there are multiple JS objects (in reality they are `json`'s) like this the form creation has to be dynamic. I have accomplished this like so

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { TextInput } from "./textInput";
import { SelectInput } from "./selectInput";
import { FiledType } from "./formTypes";

const formInput: FiledType = {
  Service_Name: {
    required: true,
    type: "text",
    constraint: {
      min: 3,
      max: 15,
      format: "alpha-hyphen-numeric"
    }
  },
  Content_Type: {
    required: true,
    type: "select",
    options: ["Markdown", "HTML"]
  },
  Remarks: {
    required: false,
    type: "text",
    constraint: {
      max: 30
    }
  }
};

export default App = (): JSX.Element => {
  const form = useForm({ mode: "all" });

  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = form;
  const { errors } = formState;

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
          {Object.keys(formInput).map((item) =>
            formInput[item].type === "text" ? (
              <TextInput
                key={item}
                name={item}
                formItemData={formInput[item]}
                register={register}
                errors={errors}
              />
            ) : (
              <SelectInput
                key={item}
                name={item}
                formItemData={formInput[item]}
                register={register}
                errors={errors}
              />
            )
          )}
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Based on "type" in the `json`, one of the `TextInput`, `DateInput` or `SelectInput` is rendered. The `TextInput` component is like below.

```
import React from "react";
import { FormFieldPropType } from "./formTypes";

export const TextInput = ({
  register,
  name,
  formItemData,
  errors
}: FormFieldPropType) => {
  const formName = name.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={formName}>{name}</label>
      <div>
        <input
          {...register(formName, {
            required: formItemData["required"],
            maxLength: formItemData["constraint"]?.max,
            minLength: formItemData["constraint"]?.min
          })}
          type="text"
          id={formName}
          name={formName}
          placeholder={name}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

All of this is working fine. However, now there is a requirement to render additional field(s) based on the content of another filed. For example, if the user selects `Markdown` for the field "Content Type", I should add a "text" filed right under it named "Folder Location". If the user selects `HTML`, nothing needs to be done.

I am not able to figure out how to add this additional filed conditionally. Can any one help? Thanks.

The working code (without syyling) can be found here -> https://codesandbox.io/s/reac-hook-form-r66n5w?file=/src/textInput.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you will need to keep track of the values of your form fields. Fortunately, react-hook-form provides the watch function, which allows you to monitor the value of a specified input. Using watch, you can conditionally render the additional "Folder Location" field when the "Content Type" is "Markdown".

Here's how you can implement this:

Use watch to monitor the Content_Type field
First, import the watch function from your form object, and use it to watch the Content_Type field:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState, watch } = form;
const contentTypeValue = watch("content-type");
```

Conditionally render the "Folder Location" input
You can now check the contentTypeValue to decide whether to render the "Folder Location" input:

```
{contentTypeValue === "Markdown" && (
<TextInput
name="Folder Location"
formItemData={{
  required: true,
  type: "text",
  constraint: {
    max: 30,
  },
  }}
 register={register}
 errors={errors}
 />
)}
```

This code will render the "Folder Location" input right below the "Content Type" input if the "Markdown" option is selected.

Update the App component
Incorporate the above changes into your App component:

```
export default App = (): JSX.Element => {
const form = useForm({ mode: "all" });

const { register, handleSubmit, formState, watch } = form;
const { errors } = formState;

const contentTypeValue = watch("content-type");

const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
console.log(data);
};

return (
<React.Fragment>
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
      {Object.keys(formInput).map((item) => (
        <React.Fragment key={item}>
          {formInput[item].type === "text" ? (
            <TextInput
              name={item}
              formItemData={formInput[item]}
              register={register}
              errors={errors}
            />
          ) : (
            <SelectInput
              name={item}
              formItemData={formInput[item]}
              register={register}
              errors={errors}
            />
          )}
          {item === "Content_Type" && contentTypeValue === "Markdown" && 
(
            <TextInput
              name="Folder Location"
              formItemData={{
                required: true,
                type: "text",
                constraint: {
                  max: 30,
                },
              }}
              register={register}
              errors={errors}
            />
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
   </div>
 </React.Fragment>
 );
};
```

By implementing the above changes, you'll be able to render the "Folder Location" field conditionally based on the value of the "Content Type" field. Make sure to adjust the rest of your components accordingly to handle the newly added "Folder Location" field (e.g., validating its input if necessary). Let me know if this helps you mate, if you have anymore questions feel free to ask

Comment: Derrick, it did not work for me. I updated the codesandbox with your code & cannot see the new field when "Markdown" is selected.

Comment: Derrick, your code works (there was a typo in my actual JSON because of which it was not working for me earlier). As I mentioned, there are a lot of these JSON's & I have to code in such a way that conditional fields are generated for any kind of JSON (cannot hard code the `watch` and render). I will try to work towards that. Nonetheless, thank you very much for the guidance. I have up-voted & accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If Derrick's proposed soultion didn't work for you for some reason, Try this alternative.(tho Derrick's solution seems more elegant)
In the App component include a state for the selected content type and an eventHandler to update the state. Then passdown the handler to Select component

```
const [contentType, setContentType] = useState(""); // State for selected content type
const handleContentTypeChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setContentType(event.target.value); // Update the selected content type in state
}
  
<SelectInput
  ... other props
  onChange={handleContentTypeChange} // Pass the onChange handler to the SelectInput component
/>
```

In the SelectInput component, pass the onChange prop to the select element to handle the selection change

```
<select
  ... other props
  onChange={onChange} // Pass the onChange handler
>
```

Add the to be conditionally rendered component to your form.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    {Object.keys(formInput).map((item) 
    ...
    )}
    {/* Conditional rendering of the "Folder Location" field */}
    {contentType === "Markdown" && (
    <TextInput
        name="Folder_Location"
        formItemData={{
        required: true,
        type: "text",
        constraint: {
            max: 50,
        },
        }}
        register={register}
        errors={errors}
    />
    )}          
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also you will need to update FormFieldPropType

```
export type FormFieldPropType = {
  register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>;
  name: string;
  formItemData: FormItemData;
  errors: FieldErrors<FieldValues>;
  onChange : (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void, // Add the type
}
```

edit: here's a working sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reac-hook-form-forked-qz9v8g?file=/src/App.tsx)