# Add & remove fields based on value of another field in a Form created using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have created a form using the library `react-hook-form`. However, I want to add & remove fields based on value of another field in the form. An answer was provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759352/add-field-to-react-hook-form-based-on-value-of-another-field). However, the solution provided was to hardcode the conditional field manually.

Since the input for the form I am creating is dynamic, I need to make the form genration code also dynamic. I thought I would figure out adding the conditional field dynamically but have not been successfully.
I have done the following

- Create an object of objects from the `input object` which has only those fields that require conditional rendering (a variable named `fRCDObject`)
- Create a function called `generateConditionalFields` which would loop through `fRCDObject` and add/remove fields based on the condition. I what hoping to add this function in the place of the "hardcoded conditional field" portion of the code as shown in the solution on the earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759352/add-field-to-react-hook-form-based-on-value-of-another-field). But I have not been been successful.

Working form (without the conditionally generated fields) is available here --> https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-fields-8cjdl5?file=/src/App.tsx

There are 2 objects in the code (`service1` and `agency1`). When we render `service1`, the conditional fields should be created based on the "Content Type" field whereas for `agency1` , it has to be based on "Environment" field. The 'conditional' property has the details of at what value should be referred to and what additional should be rendered. Currently variable `formInput` is referencing `service1` object & can be changed to `agency1` to see the code(the code that will generate dynamic conditional fields) works fine.

Can any one help/guide? Thanks.